# Is it possible to derive a classdef class from an old-style class?

Tags: octave

Is it possible to derive a classdef class from an old-style class?

In Octave 4.0 the `ss` class is defined in the old style with `@ss` directory.
I want to derive a class with a customized `__freqresp__` method in a file `myss.m` located in `path` and with the following content:

```matlab
classdef myss < ss
methods
function x = solve_svd(A,b)
  [U,S,V] = svd(A);
  si = 1.0 ./ diag(S);
  si(~isfinite(si)) = 0;
  x = V' * diag(si) * U'*b;
endfunction

function H = __freqresp__ (sys, w, cellflag = false)

  if (sys.scaled == false)
    sys = prescale (sys);
  endif

  [a, b, c, d, e, tsam] = dssdata (sys);

  if (isct (sys))  # continuous system
    s = i * w;
  else             # discrete system
    s = exp (i * w * abs (tsam));
  endif

  H = arrayfun (@(x) c*solve_svd(s*E-A,b) + d, s, "uniformoutput", false);

  if (! cellflag)
    H = cat (3, H{:});
  endif

endfunction
endmethods
endclassdef
```

Pityingly, Octave complains about an unknown class `ss` even when the `control` package is loaded.

Comment: I think the two are incompatible in that sense, even if classdef classes support @ folders. Why not do it in the "old" style though? It is still incredibly powerful (more powerful than the 'new' if you ask me; I still prefer it to classdef).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Two reasons: 1st: I actually wanted to have a one-file approach because I am studying the problem at hand within an [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/) file. But, I meanwhile know that [this is not possible](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44036) even with `classdef`. So at least I wanted to minimize the number of additional files. 2nd: The doc of `classdef` is easier to digest. Learning to program object-oriented in Octave is definitively not the end-goal of my current investigation.

Comment: I don't know enough about org-mode to comment whether a multiple-file approach would necessarily be incompatible, but I will say this: If you want to condense code into a single file, you _really_ chose the wrong language for this, hahah! One of the defining features (and in fact 'strengths') of octave/matlab is exactly this treatment of the filesystem hierarchy as syntax. It is as much a feature of the language is indentation is to python. In that sense, the 'old' system is actually much more "matlaby/octavey" than the new one (which is more java-oriented). It's also incredibly simple to use.

Comment: There _is_ a kiiiind of workaround to this of course, which is that it is completely within your power to define those files at runtime (i.e. by generating and dumping the required code into the relevant files). Which you could obviously do using a single file. Obviously I wouldn't recommend this though...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou My current approach, which I stick to quite a while now, is using Octave sessions from Orgmode and defining functions per `function ... endfunction` when I need them. Appart of the object oriented programming this works very well with a one-file approach. Note, that part of my job is investigating numerical problems or exploring new algorithms so I often need prototype implementations that do not live for very long. But, everything about that algorithm needs to be well documented. That is definitively a job for Orgmode with its source blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm answering from a MATLAB perspective here because this is what I know best, but Octave has the exact same behavior here, so it applies equally to Octave.)*

The problem with `@`-style classes is that MATLAB doesn't know their properties until an object of the class is created. Thus, to use an old-style class as a base class, MATLAB would have to construct a base object just to learn what the class looks like, but calling the constructor with wrong inputs could lead to an error message. Or the constructor could do hours worth of work. It is not viable to build an object just to learn what it looks like.

I think this is the core reason for introducing the `classdef`-style classes. There are other improvements, but none as important as this one. In `@`-style classes inheritance is determined at the time of object creation, and one must manually create objects of the base class first, and merge those into the derived object being created.

---

Here's an interesting example for an `@`-style class behavior that makes it impossible to use it as a base class in a `classdef`-style class:

**@foo/foo.m:**

```matlab
function obj = foo(x)
if x
   obj = class(struct('a','a'),'foo');
else
   obj = class(struct('b','b'),'foo');
end
```

Now in MATLAB we type:

```
>> a=foo(0)
a = 
    foo object: 1-by-1
>> b=foo(1)
Error using class
[...]
>> clear classes
>> b=foo(1)
b = 
    foo object: 1-by-1
>> a=foo(0)
Error using class
[...]
```

Class `foo` changes depending on how the first object of the class is created. Once we've created an object in one way, the other way becomes illegal.

---

A solution to OP's original problem:

> In Octave 4.0 the `ss` class is defined in the old style with `@ss` directory. I want to derive a class with a customized `__freqresp__` method [...].

Instead of *deriving* a new class with a customized method, think about *overriding* the existing method. Simply create a directory `@ss`, and put a file `__freqresp__.m` in it. Make sure that your `@ss` directory lives in a directory on the Octave path that comes **before** the toolbox directory where the original class lives.

I'm assuming that the original `__freqresp__.m` is an actual method, and not a function in the class' `private` subdirectory. If so, it's not a method and cannot be overridden (see [Function Precedence](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Function-Precedence.html) in the Octave manual).

Note that you can override overloaded functions for any type, even built-in types. For example you can create a function `@double/length.m` to override the `length` function when called with a normal (double) matrix.

Comment: That's very interesting. I assumed the `class` function would be permissive, as long as methods can cope. What is the underlying mechanism (or rationale) which prevents instances from both constructions from being possible at the same time?

Comment: @Tasos: It is the `class` call that creates not only the object, but also the definition of what the class looks like. I presume the system is not designed to handle more than one definition of a class.

Comment: Actually, now that you say it, why is a class more than just a label attached to the struct specifying what class it is? Why does the system need to know or keep track of which members the class has?

Comment: @Tasos: It just occurred to me, maybe this constraint is to prevent two different classes with the same name to be used together. If the members are different, it is likely that they're different classes that got the same name by chance/accident. As in installing two toolboxes that each define a class `image` or `polygon` or whatever other common name.

Comment: Hm ... unlikely ... for one thing, one of the classes would be shadowed in the first place; this is more likely to cause bugs than solve them in that scenario ... Yes that's what I meant, I expected it to be more of a label thing, or simply attaching some extra properties in a relatively naive manner, like e.g. in R. A quick look [at the source code](https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/512591ccb174/libinterp/octave-value/ov-class.cc#l1691) confirms it's as you say; a class "exemplar" is created at first call, and used for comparisons will all subsequent objects. Interesting. :)

Answer (score 2):

Extending my answer in the comments to an example.

Like I said in the comments, I don't think mixing classdef and classic object-oriented styles is possible. Therefore I would use the 'classic' OO-style to perform the 'overload' instead, which is fairly straightforward anyway.

However, like lots of other syntax in matlab/octave, the classic style uses filesystem semantics to define the respective namespaces, and you have the added requirement that you'd like to code all of this functionality in a single file.

The obvious workaround that comes to mind then, is to create the necessary files/namespaces on the filesystem 'on the fly', and then load that class definition as appropriate in your main code later. Obviously, this isn't really the recommended way to work with classes (new *or* old), however, if you really *must* work from a single file, then it is not that difficult to accomplish either.

Here's a (standalone) example demonstrating this (i.e. copy code into a script and just run the script in octave):

```
% Create class structure in a temporary directory
  ClassPath     = tempname();
  ClassDir      = fullfile( ClassPath, '@myss' );
  Constructor_m = fullfile( ClassDir, 'myss.m' );
  Freqresp_m    = fullfile( ClassDir, '__freqresp__.m' );
  mkdir( ClassPath )
  mkdir( ClassDir )

% Define constructor
  f = fopen( Constructor_m, 'w' );
  fdisp( f, '   function Out = myss( sys )           ' );
  fdisp( f, '     Out = struct();                    ' );
  fdisp( f, '     Out = class( Out, "myss", sys );   ' );
  fdisp( f, '   endfunction                          ' );
  fclose(f);

% Define overriding __freqresp__ method
  f = fopen( Freqresp_m, 'w' );
  fdisp( f, '   function H = __freqresp__ (sys, w, cellflag = false)                           ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '       if get( sys, "scaled" ) == false                                           ' );
  fdisp( f, '         sys = myss( prescale (sys) );                                            ' );
  fdisp( f, '       endif                                                                      ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '       [a, b, c, d, e, tsam] = dssdata (sys);                                     ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '       if (isct (sys))  # continuous system                                       ' );
  fdisp( f, '         s = i * w;                                                               ' );
  fdisp( f, '       else             # discrete system                                         ' );
  fdisp( f, '         s = exp (i * w * abs (tsam));                                            ' );
  fdisp( f, '       endif                                                                      ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '       H = arrayfun (@(x) c*solve_svd(s*e-a,b) + d, s, "uniformoutput", false);   ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '       if (! cellflag)                                                            ' );
  fdisp( f, '         H = cat (3, H{:});                                                       ' );
  fdisp( f, '       endif                                                                      ' );
  fdisp( f, '                                                                                  ' );
  fdisp( f, '   endfunction                                                                    ' );
  fclose(f);

% Load class definition
  addpath( ClassPath );

% Note: this does not need to be a class member (technically it wasn't one before either).
  function x = solve_svd(A,b)
    [U,S,V] = svd(A);
    si = 1.0 ./ diag(S);
    si(~isfinite(si)) = 0;
    x = V' * diag(si) * U'*b;
  endfunction

% Main code using derived 'myss' class.
  pkg load control
  a = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9]; 
  b = [10;11;12];
  stname = {'V', 'A', 'kJ' };
  sys = ss( a, b, 'stname', stname );
  mysys = myss( sys );
  disp( 'The freqresp using the overriden __freqresp__ method is:' );
  disp( __freqresp__( mysys, 5 ) );
```

Comment: The on fly approach is good. Of course this is also possible with Orgmode source blocks. I already considered it that before you posted your answer. Just requires some Elisp wiring. A thing I do not like so much is that one needs to get rid of the temporaries at an appropriate time, e.g., when the Org file is closed or Emacs is killed. Maybe, I implement that when I have some spare time. Okay "spare time" is a running joke but maybe I implement it anyway.

Comment: I am going to accept Cris' answer since he motivates why inheritance of old-style classes is not possible. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. I learned something new from it too :)

Comment: Btw, regarding 'manually getting rid of temporaries', I see no need for this. If you use the `tempname` function, this goes into your OS-specific tmpdir, and the OS will take care of this for you at the next reboot.

Answer (score 1):

No. New-style `classdef` ("MCOS") classes are a different mechanism from old-style classes, and they cannot be combined through inheritance.